# Show div depending on user logged in

Tags: php

```
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM it_task ORDER BY task_id DESC");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getquery))
{
    $id= $rows['task_id'];
    $date=$rows['date'];
    $project=$rows['project'];
    $topic=$rows['topic'];
    $instby=$rows['instby'];
    $inst=$rows['inst'];
    $dline=$rows['dline'];
    $ocome=$rows['ocome'];
    $comm=$rows['comm'];
    $fin=$rows['fin'];
    $dellink="<a href=\"delete.php?id=$rows[task_id]\" id=\"editnow\">Delete</a>";
    $editlink="<a href=\"edit.php?id=$rows[task_id]\" id=\"editnow\">Edit</a>";

$admin = "MJH";
if(($instby == $username)||($instby == $admin))
    {
        echo "<div id=\"editcont\">$editlink $dellink</div>";
    }
    else if($inst == $username)
    {
        echo "<div id=\"editcont\">$editlink <font face=\"Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\" size=\"2\">Delete</font></div>"
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div id=\"editcontdisabled\">Edit Delete</div>";
    }
```

.in my code above what i want to do is to show a  containing links depending on who is logged in.. however, when the admin logs in he will be able to see the  containing $editlink and $dellink.

.I can't seem to find where exactly have i gone wrong.. please help me with this guys! TIA! More Power!

.this is what my code looks like.

Comment: off-topic: don't use `<font>` tags - they've been deprecated for a long time. Use CSS to set your fonts instead.

Comment: Please provide some more information. For example, what kind of values do all these variables contain?

Comment: What is exactly not working ?

Comment: Hard-coding an admin value like that probably isn't advisable and you may want to rework your app and the logic. Presumably you are using sessions of some kind; you could easily set up an `admin` session value, without having to hard code values. (assuming this is your actual code)

Comment: .@Michiel Pater - the said variables contain links to an edit page for the $editlink and delete page for the $dellink..

Comment: @M42 - this code was supposed to echo out div id=\"editcont\">$editlink $dellink</div> when the logged in user is the admin.. but it turns out that it is not working.

Comment: What is the content of `$instby`, `$inst` and `$username` ? Do some `echo's` of these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(($instby == $username)||($username == $admin))
```

Comment: .no, that is what it is supposed to be.. because the edit function will be available whenever the logged in user is the same as the @inst.

Comment: now see (in new version of your question). So only one change :)

Comment: .Thank you very much! This one works! simple answer to my question.. haha.. now i see where i've done wrong! i was comparing $instby to the $admin where i was supposed to compare the $username to the $admin! Thanks A lot again! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$admin = "MJH";
if(($instby == $username)||($instby == $admin)) {
    if($inst == $username) {
        echo "<div id=\"editcont\">$editlink $dellink</div>";
        echo "<div id=\"editcont\">$editlink <font>Delete</font></div>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<div id=\"editcont\">$editlink $dellink</div>";
        echo "<div id=\"editcontdisabled\">Edit Delete</div>";
    }
}
```

Thats how i percieved you wanted it, but really, it is very hard to understand whats going on here. Are `$inst` and `$instby` meant to be different variables? Also, out of curiousity, why have you double bracketed your `if();` statements?

Hope I deciphered it correctly.

PS. I don't think `echo();`ing html is good practice.

Comment: .it's okay now, OZ_'s answer worked. Anyways, Thanks for the response. :)